# Can not remap command using mapleader and keymap

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

I am trying to set `<leader>pv` as `:Ex` but always it shows **E492: Not and editor command: ,pv**
Basically the newly added command mapping is not setting up or saving properly. I do not know what to do.

```
       vim.keymap.set("n", " ", "<Nop>", { silent = true, remap = false })

       vim.g.mapleader = " "

       vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", vim.cmd.Ex)
```

I am using NVIM 0.9.2 on MacOS and Brew with iTerm2

**Using :Telescope keymaps I can see `<Space>pv` is shown as `anonymous`**

Comment: Did you solved your problem? How could we help you further?

Comment: @Vivian De Smedt Unfortunately, no. Since, I am using brew and I have vim, nvim, lunarvim all installed and If nobody else is facing the issue prominently, it must have been some conflict from my side. Once I get the chance to find the issue or solution again I will definitely give an update. For now I am not using vim/vnim as it takes to much time for a starter like me, but I will definitely look around at spare time. A lot of thanks to the community and you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
lua vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", '<cmd>:Ex<cr>', { remap = false })
```

Comment: Still same issue **E492: Not and editor command: pv**

Comment: Do you put the command in `init.vim` or in `init.lua` or do you execute it from the Neovim command prompt?

Comment: You should type the keys Space,p,v in Normal mode @piedpipr

Comment: @piedpipr what @Ben suspect is that you are actually in command mode or that you are typing `: pv` and not just ` pv`.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I am using Lua only

Comment: @D.BenKnoble @VivianDeSmedt No actually ``: pv`` is what I typed and in Normal Mode, I even tried setting ``,`` as the leader which is setting properly but my ``<leader>pv`` or any other custom <leader> based remap won't work. So for now I am just using LunarVim.

Comment: But what if you don't type the colon (`:`) and only type: <space>`pv`?